# Copy workspace in a structure

Tags: matlab, vector, structure, workspace

I have about 50 vectors in my workspace and I want to save them in structure.
At the end I want to access to each vector in this way:  Structurename.vectorname
What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you really want the variables `Test1.results` and `Test2.results`. Maybe you much rather want to have `Test(1).results` and `Test(2).results`, which you can get by this:

```
 Test = struct();
 for i = 1:10
     result = rand(1,5); % compute the result
     Test(i).result = result; % bookkeeping
 end
```

Now you can even iterate over your results, where the result of the i-th simulation is stored in `Test(i).result`.

Comment: Dear Nras
Thanks for your answer. Actually my results are come from different simulation and I have vectors on my workspace.
I just want to group them in something like a folder that I could access to any of the former simulation results.
So here the results are vectors which are already in my workspace and they are many !

Comment: Dealing with many vectors at once is always a pain. I suggest you should rethink your structure there from the beginning. Can you not save them in a cell or a structure right when you load them / simulate them? Do they all have the same shape, so maybe you can save them in a single matrix? Can you maybe give an example?

Comment: Actually the easiest example I can give is that:  
let's consider I have 50 vectors in my workspace and I want to copy them in a structure. How can I do that?

Comment: The problem is: you don't want to come to the situation of having that 50 vectors in your workspace. The problem is: how do you get 50 single vectors in your workspace? Can't this be avoided by storing them directly in a structure/cell/matrix?

Comment: No actually the issue is that in any case I will have 50 vectors in my workspace. Now in worspace 50 vectors are available and I want to move them into a structure. Unfortunately I do not know how ! I cannot address them from the beginning and I only want to group them after I have all vectors in my workspace.

Comment: It can be done with ``eval()``. Please update your question and state how the vectors are named.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the answer and question but I could not understand how can I use this command for grouping ! could you please do a favor and give me a small example?

Comment: IN order not to turn this into a extended discussion, this will be the last comment on that. By "please update your question and state how the vectors are named" i really meant: please update your question and state how the vectors are named. We need to address 50 vectors, so we need to know the variables names of the 50 vectors in order to do so. This is an import part of the problem and you cannot be helped further until you reveal how your vectors are called.